# How to implement ajax in WordPress plugins?

Tags: wordpress

I am a new on wp develop plugins...

```
    <td><img class="dele" src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'images/delete.png' , __FILE__ )?> " onClick="getsize1(<?php echo $Opportunitiy->ID; ?>)"/></td>
            </tr>


  <?php } ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function getsize1(id){
alert (id);
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
if(xmlhttp.responseText)
{
alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
//window.location.reload();
}
}
}


xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo plugins_url( 'delete.php' , __FILE__ )?>?id="+<?php echo $Opportunitiy->ID; ?>,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

  </script>
```

I have write this way in main plugin file.. and i call a delete.php this way..

```
<?php 

global $wpdb;

var_dump($wpdb);
if (is_object($wpdb) && is_a($wpdb, 'wpdb')) {
echo "DELETE FROM `syn_account` WHERE ID = ".$_GET['id'];
 $sql=$wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM `syn_account` WHERE ID = ".$_GET['id']);
 $wpdb->query($sql);


//$wpdb->delete("syn_account",  array('ID' =>$_GET['id']));
}
?>
```

i have not connect other files its display errors
when i print var_dump than i got a null value plz help me..

Answer (score 0):

why not using jquery ?

wordpress has native support for jquery and it's mych more easy then javascript.

i recommend reading om action and hooks,  you can develop nothing without know them.
on your specific request read here:
http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/

good luck.